# Ignore some content of the website

Tags: seo

I have the best SEO possible, every html tag is 110% right, seo site checkup results are 95%, pagespeed insights Is 100% (thanks ahahah), however, common keywords and keyword cloud always show content that shouldn't be there, like usernames, comments, sites zone titles (like "Comments title bar") etc...

Is there anyway to hide this words from google? i really think that google don't understand my website.

Comment: @user3465632 As it is, this question is too broad. If you can narrow it down to something specific that you want Google to not index (e.g., just comments, or titles...), then please edit the question to be specific to that, and also try to provide an example of the content and code. Additonally, you should clarify what you mean by: `common keywords and keyword cloud always show content that shouldn't be there` (i.e., where is that displayed, and can you provide screenshots?).